# How to create a single directory using the free space of three servers?

Tags: nfs, unionfs

For the sake of simplicity , is it possible to map somehow the free disk space on three servers into a single directory and have the filesystem handle the sharding?

I believe https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs  might be it but I find the documentation a bit terse and can't figure it out.

Comment: That's what cluster filesystems are for.

Answer (score 0):

Following  Gerald Schneider's comment since I already had a Docker swarm ongoing on my three hosts, I have used https://github.com/gongonpower/glusterfs-swarm successfully to set gluster up.

The only change necessary was, for this use case, the create command should be simply

`gluster volume create gv0 gfsc1:/bricks/brick1/gv0 gfsc2:/bricks/brick1/gv0 gfsc3:/bricks/brick1/gv0`

The repository uses "replica 3" which is not what we need here. Also, if you managed to create the wrong volume, after removing it to re-add the same bricks the `--force` argument needs to be added to the end of the next `create` command.